# Make VS code choose Node.js environment by default when debugging js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using VS code v1.45 to debug a simple nodejs file.

I am testing out a simple node.js file.

```
var msg = 'Hello World';
console.log(msg);
```

When I press F5, I get prompted to choose the environment. See screenshot below.

[image]

This is a hassle. How do I make VS code choose Node.js environment by default without prompting?

My node.js is installed at `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

[image]

Click on "create a launch.json file" on the debug panel found on left-hand side. Then, click Node.js when prompted. Subsequently, Node.js will be the default environment.

Credit goes to someone by the name of drunktimelord.

Comment: Not a good answer. When you look at the launch.json file created, it works only specifically on a particular js file. You'll be prompted again when you try with a new js file.

Comment: @guagay_wk you can make the `launch.json` affect all the files by using `"program": "${file}"` instead of the explicit file path

Answer (score 5):

I will build on answer by user3848207

Delete any existing launch.json file first. Otherwise, no effect when you click on "create a launch.json file" on the debug panel.

Now, click on "create a launch.json file" on the debug panel found on left-hand side. Then, click Node.js when prompted. Subsequently, Node.js will be the default environment.

Manually edit `launch.json` such that `"program": "${file}"`. Otherwise, when you press F5, it will run on specific js file and not on actively open file.

launch.json should look like this.

[image]

This answer works on VS code v1.45

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Manually edit launch.json such that "program": "${file}"   - this helped.

Comment: this should be the selected answer